# Proving Union and Intersection of Power Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am asked to disprove that:
$$\mathcal P(A\cup B) \subseteq \mathcal P(A) \cup \mathcal P(B) .....(1)$$

I am also asked to prove that:
$$\mathcal P(A) \cup \mathcal P(B) \subseteq \mathcal P(A\cup B).....(2)$$ $$\mathcal P(A\cap B) = \mathcal P(A) \cap \mathcal P(B).....(3)$$
Where $\mathcal P(A)$ represents the Power Set of $A$

For (1), I have somewhat managed to prove it, so there must be a mistake in my proof:

Let $X \in \mathcal P(A\cup B)$ then by definition $X \subseteq A \cup B$

This means that $X$ is either a subset of $A$, $B$ or $A \cup B$. Therefore $X\subseteq A$ or $X\subseteq B$ and hence $X \in \mathcal P(A) \cup \mathcal P(B)$ (I find something really wrong with this line, but I am not sure where am I wrong at.)

For (2), I did this:

Let $X \in \mathcal P(A) \cup \mathcal P(B)$, then $X\in \mathcal P(A)$ or $X\in \mathcal P(B)$

Case 1: $X\in \mathcal P(A)$, this means $X\subseteq A \implies X\subseteq A\cup B \implies X \in \mathcal P(A\cup B)$

Case 2: $X\in \mathcal P(B)$, this means $X\subseteq B \implies X\subseteq A\cup B \implies X \in \mathcal P(A\cup B)$

So in both cases, the statements are true. The questtion is, do I need to consider $X\in \mathcal P(A) \cap \mathcal P(B)$?

For (3), I did this:

(Backward Direction) Let $X\in \mathcal P(A) \cap \mathcal P(B)$, then $X\in \mathcal P(A)$ and $X\in \mathcal P(B)$. Meaning that $X\subseteq A$ and $X\subseteq B$ so it must be true that $X\subseteq A\cap B$ and hence $\mathcal P(A \cap B)$

(Forward Direction) Let $X \in\mathcal P(A \cap B)$, then $X\subseteq A\cap B$. This means that $X\subseteq A$ and $X\subseteq B$ which implies that $X\in \mathcal P(A) \cap \mathcal P(B)$.

Any help or advice on my way of proving is really appreciated!

Comment: For 1) you should try A={1} and B={2} and just compute the power sets. You are right that your proof breaks down at the line you have a problem with. In particular, just because X is a subset of the union does not mean it is entirely contained in either A or B.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say

> This means that $X$ is either a subset of $A$, $B$ or $A \cup B$. Therefore $X\subseteq A$ or $X\subseteq B$ and hence $X \in \mathcal P(A) \cup \mathcal P(B)$

you cannot deduce that $X \subseteq A$ or $X \subseteq B$.  You could have some of $X$ be a subset of $A$ and the rest be a subset of $B$.  Take $A=\{0,1,2\}, B=\{2,3,4\}, X=\{1,4\}$ for example

For $2$ you don't need to worry about $X \subseteq A \cap B$.  It is covered in both your cases.

Comment: Many thanks for the help, could I just check that if my proof for (3) is correct as well? Thank you!